# When I reload the master window, the link to the popup window is lost

Tags: javascript

When I reload the master window, the link to the popup window is lost. How do I save it?

More detailed.
There is a page with data. If you need to change something, the button opens a pop-up window. The pop-up window sends data to the server, and after confirming the server reloads itself and the parent page.
But at the same time, if the parent page is closed/reloaded by itself, it should close the pop-up window.

It was implemented like this (quite a long time ago):

On the parent page:

```
<script>
 
// variable of the child window
var subWin;
 
// flag whether to close the child window
var subWindowsClose = true;
 
// function for opening a child window
function openSubWindow()
{
        subWin = window.open('editingdata.html');
}

// function for closing the pop-up window when closing/restarting
// if the flag is set
window.onunload = function() {
        if(subWinClose == true) {
                if(typeof subWin !== 'undefined') { subWin.close(); };
        };
};
 
</script>
```

In the pop-up window

```
<script>
function windowsReload() {
        window.opener.subWinClose = false;
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.location.reload();
};
</script>
```

If data is entered correctly in the pop-up window, the "windowsReload" function is called, which sets the "do not close the pop-up window" flag on the parent page, and reloads everything.

"var" is now deprecated. Guidelines do not recommend using global variables.
How to do without them in this case - I don't know yet. I'm trying to use global objects.

The problem is that the pop-up window variable is lost (= undefined) when the parent window is reloaded, even if it is added to the global array,
That is, after the first reboot of the mother window, the pop-up window does not close itself.

What can you think of that would modernize, but keep the functionality?

P.S. Sorry for my English, I'm just learning.

Comment: Take a look at the [onbeforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: I looked at it, but I didn't see how it could help me.